# How to integrate camera image into physics engine?

Tags: collision-detection, augmented-reality, video-processing, interaction, physics-engine

I recently came across [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u8q6efIibA0) and would like to implement something similar. The basic approach is clear: I have to threshold the image and check if a virtual object collides with the remaining foreground.

Instead of implementing the physics myself, I'd like use an engine like Box2D. But how do I integrate the thresholded image into the physics engine so it is possible to interact with virtual objects?

Answer (score 4):

You want to do edge detection.  There are open source algorithms for this. While you can threshold as you suggest, good edge detection algorithms will work without this and might be more fun because you should not need the solid white background to get interesting results.  Check out OpenCV http://www.mathworks.com/products/imaq/demos.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/imaq/demoimaqsl_edgedetection.html for starters.

Edge detectors ultimately produce vectors in pixel coordinates as output.  You'll want to turn these into Box2D `b2_staticBody` objects that move under program control according to the same time series as the video frames that generated the edges.  Now you can add kinetic objects to the Box2D environment and they will behave as though the edges are immovable solids.

Finlly you'll have to overlay the Box2D output onto the video frames. OpenCV should help with that, too. Or you could use a video editing tool.

It would be considerably more work, but you might even get this to work in real time. Note if you have access to MATLAB, it has a video frame rate edge detector in one of the toolboxes.